# Git: Deleting Remote Branch Doesn't Synch?

Tags: git

So on Computer A, I did the following.

```
git branch test
git push
```

On a different machine Computer B, I pull the changes and track the remote branch test

```
git pull --all
git checkout -t origin/test
```

all is good.

But when I delete the test branch on Computer A and push the changes doing the following:

```
git checkout master 
git push origin --delete test
git branch -D test
```

Now back on Computer B, I do the following

```
git pull --all
git branch -a
```

test shows up which is OK, since I didn't delete it locally.
However, `remotes/origin/test` also shows up.

I have a feeling that `git pull --all` doesn't update the remote branches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove from your local repo branches that were deleted remotely, you have to run `git fetch --prune`.

If you have a local branch tracking the deleted branch, your local branch won't be removed, but tracking will be unset.